# Onclick not working. Cannot read property 'click' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclicklistener

I keep receiving the following error from the browser console when loading my script into my [Magento store](http://phoneparter.com/). All that it is listening for is an onclick event on a div yet I receive this error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null."

The script works in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1dvswnm/9/) so I'm really not quite sure why it isn't working. I've tried enclosing it within a $( document ).ready() as well but I receive the same error.

**Code:**

```
var step = 0;
var deviceType = "";
var modelType = "";

function showGen(){
    $('.phoneTypes').css("display", "none");

    if (deviceType == "Samsung"){
      $('.sphoneGens').css("display", "block");
    }
    if (deviceType == "iPhone"){
      $('.iphoneGens').css("display", "block");
    }
    if (deviceType == "iPad"){
      $('.ipadGens').css("display", "block");
    }
}

// Pick Device Type
$('.choicelabel').click(function(){
    deviceType = $(this).children('input').val();
    showGen();
});

//Pick Device Gen
$('.choiceType').click(function(){
    modelType = $(this).children('input').val();
    //$(".iphoneGens").css("display", "none");
    console.log(deviceType);
    console.log(modelType);
    $(this).parents(".row").hide();
});
```

Any help debugging this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Then that means choiceType or choicelabel doesnt exist

Comment: Should not it to return empty jQuery collection then?

Comment: I notice that most classes are camelCased except for '.choicelabel', is that a typo where it should be '.choiceLabel' ?

Comment: Sounds like jQuery is not being loading correctly due to the fact $() should never return null. Or something other than jQuery is `$`

Comment: I think, your `$` was overwritten by some non-jQuery lib. Try `jQuery('.choicelabel').click`

Comment: Questions of this nature should show the offending markup associated with the error which is in `$('.choicelabel').click(function(){
    deviceType = $(this).children('input').val();
    showGen();
});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here.
  // And document is ready too
});
```

---

**What's the issue?**

`Prototype.js` was loaded after `jQuery` and was overwrite global `$` symbol.

**How can we deal with it?**

You still have `jQuery` global to use. Just use it everywhere, where you want to use `$`.

```
// Pick Device Type
jQuery('.choicelabel').click(function(){
    deviceType = jQuery(this).children('input').val();
    showGen();
});

//Pick Device Gen
jQuery('.choiceType').click(function(){
    modelType = jQuery(this).children('input').val();
    //jQuery(".iphoneGens").css("display", "none");
    console.log(deviceType);
    console.log(modelType);
    jQuery(this).parents(".row").hide();
});
```

You can also to define some shorthand for simplify it:

```
jQ = jQuery;
```

---

Common best practice for cases like this is to use [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) wrap for your code:

```
;(function($){ // see note-1
  // Use $ here! It's jQuery now
  $(function(){
    // be sure DOM was loaded before work with it(ex: binding events)
  });
})(jQuery);
```

This adds nothing to global scope and achieves what we need.
You always can inject some other libraries(prototypejs?) with alias what you want to this IIFE.

*note-1: Semicolon before IIFE protects javascript from previous expression with missed semicolon to be interpreted as function call.*

---

jQuery itself provides shorthand for this case:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here.
  // And document is ready too
});
```

Comment: some jQuery plugins may rely on `$` global symbol. They're worse designed plugins and all you can do is wrap its code with IIFE from an answer. May be you want merge all of them to some `jquery.libs.js` for this. Or you can simplify your dependencies: Are you realy need both jQuery and Prototype.js?

Comment: `jQuery is not defined` - Just add onLoad stuff:  `jQuery(function(){ ... })`

Comment: Prototype is loaded from a Magento theme. Not really sure what functionality is using it. I've wrapped the whole function with the IIFE but still no functionality. You can view the javascript file here: http://phoneparter.com/js/parter.js

Comment: `jQuery.getScript('http://phoneparter.com/js/parter.js')` in the console does all stuff to be worked. So, you need just onLoad stuff: `$(function(){/*All code here*/})`

Comment: That has fixed it. Thank you very much for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

That site isn't using jQuery, it's using [prototypejs](http://www.prototypejs.org)

Comment: It actually uses both, but jQ was overwritten. It's just some less lucky :)