# Setting click to not created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

this is my first question here and I hope I'm asking it correct.
I'm making an userscript. The website has a chat and when a user for example clicks a message it should copy it. The website has removed right click and selecting. I know how to copy the message,  but I don't know how to add the click feature part.

This is the code I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.msg').click(function(){
      $('#someinput').val($(this).text())
      .select();
      document.execCommand('copy');    
      });
});
```

This gives me the error Cannot read property 'click' of null, and I guess that is because the chat message isn't created yet. How do I fix this?

Comment: try   $('.msg').on("click", function(){ }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396702/onclick-not-working-cannot-read-property-click-of-null

Comment: I don't think that is because of lack of `.msg` in document. The `.mgs` doesn't exist in https://jsfiddle.net/ofvvebe4/ but the error doesn't returned.

Comment: Well I don't know... It works now and that's the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use jQuery event delegation: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation

If your .msg elements are inside a container you can write

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').on('click', '.msg', function() {
        // your click function
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed!

Comment: 'You must'?? There's no must.